# How do I connect to my windows server 2008 hosted on a virtual box?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtualbox

I've hosted Windows Server 2008 Enterprise on a virtualbox and set up IIS7 with ASP.NET. 
Now I wonder what I have to do to be able to connect to the virtualbox from the computer I'm running the virtualbox on?

I tried entering the ip supplied by ipconfig from inside the box; 10.0.2.15 which doesn't seem to work, like so "http://10.0.2.15". I read something that VirtualBox uses NAT (which I've confirmed is the case), but I don't know what to do about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The default network options are wrong for this scenario, but I'm not currently at a place where I can lookup the right option or where to go to change it.  If I remember later when I'm there and you don't have an answer yet I'll post it.

Comment: So I should change it to a bridget network or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to changed to bridged networking so your host (the computer running virtual box) and guest (windows 2008) will be on the same "network" and see each other.